# mongodb get document with max length of a specific array field nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

This is type of document

```
{
  _id: string, 
  attributes: [{},{}],
  collection_name: string
}
```

i want to get the id and attributes whose attributes length is maximum, so I am using this query

```
.aggregate([
            { $match: { collection_name: collection } },
            
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                id: { "$first": "$_id" },
                attributes: { "$first": "$attributes" },
                maxLengthOfYArray: {
                  $max: {
                    $size: {
                      $ifNull: ["$attributes", []]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]).toArray();
```

but this is returning correct max length but not the correct document, the document it returns has only 5 attributes

what is the issue?

**Update**

documents

```
[
    {
        _id : "1",
        attributes : [{a:1},{b:2}],
        collection_name : "A"
    },
    {
        _id : "2",
        attributes : [{b:2}],
        collection_name : "B"
    }

]
```

and the result I am expecting

```
{
  _id: "1",
  attributes : [{a:1},{b:2}],
  maxLengthOfArray : 2 
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample document along with the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this would be to add a new field for `maxLengthOfArray` and set the value to be the `$size` of `attributes` array. From there, use `$sort` to get the largest `maxLengthOfArray` at the top, then limit the return to one item. From there we can `$project` necessary fields we want to return.

[Check out a live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5AAyExWoYLY)

***Edit:**** I forgot to add the `$match` for collection name, but you should be able to add that as the first aggregation step. Let me know if you want me to update my answer, although I doubt you'll need help with that part. :)

#### Database

```
[
  {
    _id: "1",
    attributes: [
      {
        a: 1
      },
      {
        b: 2
      }
    ],
    collection_name: "A"
  },
  {
    _id: "2",
    attributes: [
      {
        b: 2
      }
    ],
    collection_name: "B"
  },
  {
    _id: "3",
    attributes: [
      {
        a: 1
      },
      {
        b: 2
      },
      {
        b: 2
      },
      {
        b: 2
      }
    ],
    collection_name: "A"
  }
]
```

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      maxLengthOfArray: {
        $size: "$attributes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      maxLengthOfArray: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      attributes: 1,
      maxLengthOfArray: 1
    }
  }
])
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "a": 1
      },
      {
        "b": 2
      },
      {
        "b": 2
      },
      {
        "b": 2
      }
    ],
    "maxLengthOfArray": 4
  }
]
```

Comment: is there any way if i can skip adding the field to eveery document?

Comment: @SunilGarg it looks like this is the most efficient way to natively sort by array size/length. Keep in mind it doesn't actually add that field for all documents in the database, it is only added to the query results. It is needed for this query. Why do you want to skip that part?